# .htaccess, mod_rewrite, regex with directory and filetype

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to do a rewrite with the following conditions:

1. Directory is /images
2. file has a .jpg, .png or .gif extension

I want to redirect to the following

```
/images/?file=filename.extension
```

This is not working:

```
RewriteRule /images/(.*\.jpg|png|gif) /images/?file=$1
```

Example:

`/images/example.jpg` => `/images/?file=example.jpg`

Thanks

Comment: http://www.rubular.com or http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ or ... ,always test your regex

Comment: I just checked it in rubular and it said to escape the forward slash but it didn't help eventough the match and capture are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need parens to group the extensions.

```
/images/(.*\.(jpg|png|gif))
```

Comment: Enkay, can you enable logging? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog

Comment: It stays blank... not sure it's configured properly.

Comment: Can you post your .htaccess here?

Answer (score 0):

In the .htaccess file, the path is stripped of the leading slash so you need to start with a `images/` instead of `/images/`. Also, you can start with a `^` to match the beginning of the path so that paths like `/blahblah/images/something.gif` won't get rewritten. Finally, your paren will match `foo.jpg` but not `foo.png` or `foo.gif`. Try this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^images/(.+\.(jpg|png|gif)) /images/?file=$1
```

Comment: The leading slash is remove in Directory or htaccess context, not in VirtualHost context.

Comment: Is this .htaccess file in your document root you in the "images" directory? Actually, check my edit, removed leading slash in the target.

Comment: The .htaccess file in the document root. The images directory is an Alias set in virtualhost. Does that matter?

Comment: No, if it's in the document root, then it should be fine. It's working in my .htaccess. What error are you getting?

Comment: Is this creating some kind of loop? The file it redirects to also fits the regex. Is there a way to modify it so that the filename cannot start with a question mark?

Comment: It shouldn't, rewriting stops when the original path starts with the same thing as the rewritten path. Also, the query string (?file=) isn't part of the match in RewriteRule. There must be something else that's messing it up.