# Need to redirect all requests for certain url with pdfs to a file with the file name as a parameter

Tags: url, pdf, url-rewriting

I am extremely new to rewrite conditions, and have the following need:

I need to develop a rewrite rule that will catch all requests for a url structured like the following:
http://www.marktechopto.com/pdfs/product/XTE_HV.pdf

Once entered into the users browser, I want the rule to match on the path "pdfs/product/[filename.pdf]" and map the request to another file like this: pdf.cfm?pdf=[filename.pdf]

I've tried many variations, and google searches, but nothing seems to work.

You can try the url above, and see where I am now.  I am using ISAPI Rewwrite v3.

The current rules I am attempting to use are:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web_content/pdf/
RewriteRule ^(.+\.pdf)$ /pdf/products/DataSheet$1 [L]
```

Thank you all for any help you can provide.

-=Mark

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060446/htaccess-mod-rewrite-regex-with-directory-and-filetype

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [how RewriteRules are parsed](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond).

In a nutshell: If the left part of the rule matches, then all preceding conditions are checked and only if those are true the right part of the rule is applied.

So your rule is currently doing nothing, as the condition doesn't apply. I also don't see a pattern by the paths you provide in the question and the ones used in the rewrite rule  (pdfs/product > /web_content/pdf, pdf.cfm? > ??). Besides, I think you got the `$1` variable wrong…

Assuming your question contains the paths you really want:

```
RewriteRule ^pdfs/product/(.+\.pdf)$ pdf.cfm?pdf=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response.  I put the rule in place you mentioned and it still doesn't work.  When I put your rule in the reg expression tester with my test url, it doesn't find a pattern.  When I save the rule, and visit the test url in my browser, it just gives a 404.  Any ideas?  My rule is:
RewriteRule ^pdfs/product/(.+\.pdf)$ /pdf.cfm?pdf=$1 [L] My test url is:  http://www.marktechopto.com/pdfs/product/XTE_HV.pdf

Comment: @user2337607 I updated the rule and tested it at http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ with your test url and the following result: `This rule was met, the new url is http://www.marktechopto.com/pdf.cfm?pdf=XTE_HV.pdf The tests are stopped because the L in your RewriteRule options`

Comment: @user2337607 Your welcome. As you seem to be a new SO user, please take a look at the FAQ/help and at this [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).